# Would AKKA Streams Suite to my requirement

Tags: java, playframework, akka, akka-stream

I have two text files which are very large (**at least 6 laksh lines in each file**). And the contents of the file would be in column wise and each file would have 2 columns each and one of them is a common column in both files.

Now i need to read the 2 files and map a common column between the two files and insert the final row into the database which now has 3 columns.

As of i am using **play framework with JAVA** to read the files separately and store the content of the first file in a list and read the second file by 1000 lines at once and once 1000 lines are read then the mapping of those 1000 files is done and the final records are inserted into database then the next 1000 lines are read and processed, this process continuous until the second file ends.

This worked fine when the files are smaller but Now this is becoming a time consuming process and also there is a vulnerability as we store the contents of the first file in an array which might lead to Heap Space error later.

So while looking at alternative options i found that Akka - Streams to be interesting and performance seems be lot better while using this . But i am not sure how exactly would it fit to my scenario as i am dealing with reading multiple files and mapping them later on.

So could you guys please suggest me whether it is advisable to use Akka streams here if so could also give me high-level insight on how it can be implemented in my case?

Comment: Can you assume the values in the 'common column' are sorted somehow?

Comment: What is the nature of order of values in common column in both files? Are they random or sorted or have sames values at same line?

Comment: Sorted but for mapping the required values will not be in same line in both files

Comment: Sounds like a job for a relational database. Import the two files A&B and do an inner/outer/full join?